# Why does ASP.NET terminates async requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, fiddler, dotnet-httpclient

I know that this is not the proper way to write code, but I still like to understand this behavior - whenever I do an async HTTP request without waiting for the result, it seems like the request is terminated? (I do not see it on fiddler).

Code sample:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost.fiddlerhttpclient/");
                    var response = client.GetAsync("zzzz");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I change the code to:

```
var response = client.GetAsync("zzzz").Result;
```

I do see it on fiddler. I don't understand why - I would expect that the request would still keep processing in background somehow, so why doesn't it?

Comment: You do not `await` the result. In other words: you have not registered any callback.

Comment: @Marco - Yes I know that, but I would expect the request to proceed anyway in the background even when no one is "listening" to the result - it shouldn't be aborted.

Comment: But you are disposing your `HttpClient` immediately after starting fetch that url, cancelling all pending operations.

Comment: @Evk - You are correct, if I remove the using I get the expected behavior.  Please write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disposing `HttpClient` cancels all pending requests, if any. You are disposing your client (because of `using` block) immediately after starting request with `GetAsync`, so there is almost no chance for it to start making actual http request which will appear in fiddler.